SSISDB package runs fine but if put in Job it fails
I have a SSIS package that is driving me crazy. When I build it in Visual Studio it works flawlessly, when I run it as a package from SQL management it works great. But when I try and set it up as a job it fails with an Exception from HRESULT:0x800A03EC. I have researched it and tried everything I could find, still fails.
The part it is failing on is the opening and saving a XLSX to a PDF using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel below is my script in a Script Task. Thanks in advance for any help.
        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            // This script saves a xlsx to a PDF file, make sure to set the page orientation and size in the original excel file before the package runs this formats the PDF   
            {
                String V_Excel = Dts.Variables["User::XLSXRepFilePath"].Value.ToString();
                String V_PDF = Dts.Variables["User::PDFRepFilePath"].Value.ToString();

                Application app = new Application();
                Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(V_Excel);
                wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, (V_PDF));

                //Clean up
                wkb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkb);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkb);

                //if (worksheet != null)
                //    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
                GC.Collect();
            }


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

Changing code, added the interop, upgraded to the newest versions of SQL Management, Visual Studio.

Sounds like the drivers/dll's to run the package are not installed on the server or a different version is compared to what you are running locally.

The Visual Studio I am using is on the same server that hosts the SQL. Where would I find where to put the DLL files so SQL can see it?

It would be on the server where you are creating the jobs.

Yes, I got that, I meant what directory? Does it go in the c:\windows\assembly directory?

If you install them from a package/.exe file it will put them where they are needed.  If you put them anywhere else manually you would have to manually create the assembly reference in the windows assembly I believe (been a long time since I have done it that way so would have to look that up).

This question is similar to: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while running through SQL Agent. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The job is running with different user and different location. Make sure that

everything on the new location (the server) is well configured and you have the drivers
and that the server user that execute the job has access.

When you look executions (from reports on the SSIS package) you can see which user executes it.
